# How would defining `that = this` help me create private variables/members?

Tags: javascript, object

I was reading [Douglas Crawford's piece](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) on creating private variables in javascript classes.

In it he says you have to state `that = this` in order to "make the object available to private methods". However, I was able to build an example which has private members, private methods and public methods without defining `that = this`:

```
function Form(id_code) {

    //private variable
    var id_code = id_code;
    var color = '#ccc';

    //private method
    function build_style_attribute() {
        return 'style="background-color:'+color+'"';
    }

    //public method
    this.render = function() {
        return '<div '+build_style_attribute()+'>'+id_code+'</div>';
    }
}

var formModules = new Form('modules');

$('p#test').html(formModules.render());
```

**What would specifying `that = this` allow me to do which this example does not already do?**

## Added:

Thanks @Gaby, so this is how I understand it: as the above example shows, I have access to **private** variables without using `that=this` but it does give me access to **public** variables as shown here:

```
function Form(id_code) {
    that = this;

    //private variable
    var id_code = id_code;
    var color = '#ccc';

    //public variable
    this.weight = 'bold';

    //private method
    function build_style_attribute() {
        //this will not work with either "weight" or "this.weight"
        return 'style="background-color:'+color+'; font-weight:'+that.weight+'"';
    }

    //public method
    this.render = function() {
        return '<div '+build_style_attribute()+'>'+id_code+'</div>';
    }
}

var formModules = new Form('modules');

$('p#test').html(formModules.render());
```

Comment: Good question. This has puzzled me too. Or should I say 'that' has puzzled me. I'm here all week.

Comment: you also do not have access to functions added through the prototype chain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> By **convention**, we make a private *that*
> variable. This is used to make the
> object available to the **private
> methods**.
>
> ***This is a workaround for an
> error in the ECMAScript Language
> Specification which causes this to be
> set incorrectly for inner functions***.

```
function Test() {
    var that = this;
    
    function wrongprivate(){
     return this;
    }
    
    function rightprivate(){
     return that;
    }    
    
    this.check= function (){
     console.log( wrongprivate() );
     console.log( rightprivate() );
    }
    
}

var test= new Test();
test.check();
// will output 
// window
// object{}
```

Live at http://www.jsfiddle.net/BpmQ3/1/

Comment: but as in the above example, I already have access to the object and its private variables (color) within my private method (build_style_attribute). What would be a situation in which I would need to access `color` as `that.color`?

Comment: if you wanted to access the object (*in context*) from the private method. added example.

Answer (score 0):

Without using 'that' You can also achieve rightThis:

```
function someFunction(){

    var that = this;
    function getThis(){
        return this;
    };
    function getThat(){
        return that;
    };
    return{
        getThis:getThis,
        getThat:getThat
    }

 }

var a = new someFunction();

alert(a.getThis()); // Object

alert(a.getThat()); // Object
```